# How to draw three circles and connect only two by line?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I try to draw the three dots then connect only two of them by line.

My attempts looks like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sjoxdf25/154/).

Why I get wrong circles in x0, x1, x2 coordinates?

```
for (let x = 0; x < width; x += offsetX) {
  ctx.arc(x0, y0, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.arc(x1, y1, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.arc(x2, y2, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x0, y0);
  ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
  ctx.moveTo(x2, y2);
  ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
  ctx.stroke();

  x0 += offsetX;
  x1 += offsetX;
  x2 += offsetX;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have each circle in own path:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x0, y0, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x1, y1, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
```

Here is a simplified version of your code:

```js
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 200;
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(5, 5);

let triangleWidth = 20;
let offset = 50;

let y0 = 1;
let y1 = triangleWidth;
let y2 = triangleWidth / 2;

function draw() {
  for (let y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++) {
    x0 = triangleWidth;
    x1 = triangleWidth;
    x2 = 0;

    for (let x = 0; x < canvas.width; x += offset) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x0, y0, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x1, y1, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x2, y2, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x0, y0);
      ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
      ctx.moveTo(x2, y2);
      ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
      ctx.stroke();

      x0 += offset;
      x1 += offset;
      x2 += offset;
    }
    y0 += offset;
    y1 += offset;
    y2 += offset;
  }
}

draw();
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```